# Android:Transparent space appearing on the top of list view

Tags: android, android-listview, gradient

I had requirement of using **pull to refresh** list view, so I used [Chris Banes implementation](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) of the same. I also required to set a dark transparent background on my list items. So, I used gradient. Every thing works fine except, a small empty space appearing on the top between header and listview as shown in the image below, and I need to remove it. I think its issue with gradient and not with library as I looked at the source code of library but didn't found any thing problematic.

Below is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_menu_list" >

<com.dzo.pulltorefresh.HeaderBar
    android:id="@+id/baseHeaderBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/baseHeaderBar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#050505"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is gradient that I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient 
    android:startColor="#77000000"
    android:centerColor="#88000000"
    android:endColor="#99000000"
    android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the white color space between header and list?

Comment: Its appearing beacuse of your background color of the root layout. . Just set your `RelativeLayout` background as `android:background="@android:color/background_dark"` and then check.

Comment: are you displaying your listview in normal actvity or in dialog (alert dialog)?

Comment: Its a normal activity

Comment: This is off topic, but you should not be trying to duplicate an iOS app on android. This will lead to not being featured by Google, among other bad things.

Comment: @MatthewRuno Ya, but when client demands you something, you simply cannot say no. I always try to stick with android patterns as far as I can. Anyways this question is about five months old. Thanks for your concern, you made a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `RelativeLayout` background as dark as below:

> ```
>   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >
> ```

Comment: Sorry, actually the relative layout's background is an image. I was making changes in order to see if I get any difference,and I forgot to revert back. I had edit my post. That is not actual background which I am using.

Comment: Is this drawable `@drawable/bg_menu_list` is your image or xml file ?

Comment: Does your image contains the white color ?

Comment: No, its just have view of a city